# my ".exe" made in VB do not run in Task Scheduler WIN7

Tags: windows-7, vbscript, scheduling, exe

I have made my .exe in VBscript.
My application calls Illustrator and save all the open documents.
If I run the application with double click all works correctly.

If I want to run my application in Task Scheduler in WIN7 it don't works.

Someone can help Me?

Comment: What does "don't works" mean?  Do you get an error?  Does your computer belch fire?  Does nothing happen at all?

Comment: "don't works" mean "don't start" but no error appears, no messages at all.

Comment: Sounds like your scheduled task is incorrect, then.  Is there anything in the Windows Event Log?  How did you define the task?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to invoke `wscript` from the Task Scheduler and pass in the path to your VBScript, like:

`wscript.exe C:\myscript.vbs`

Comment: Why I need wscript? if I try to run any other ".exe" it works fine.